# Airflow mysql to gcp Dag error

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm recently started working with Airflow. I'm working on DAG that:

1. Queries the MySQL database
2. Extract the query and stores it in a cloud storage bucket as a JSON file
3. Uploads stored JSON file to BigQuery

Dag imports three operators: `MySqlOperator`, `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` and `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`

I am using Airflow 1.8.0, Python 3, and Pandas 0.19.0.

Here is my Dag Code:

```
sql2gcp_csv = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(

    task_id='sql2gcp_csv',
    sql='airflow_gcp/aws_sql_extract_7days.sql',
    bucket='gs://{{var.value.gcs_bucket}}/{{ ds_nodash }}/',
    filename='{{ ds_nodash }}-account-*.json',
    schema_filename='support/file.json',
    approx_max_file_size_bytes=1900000000,
    mysql_conn_id='aws_mysql',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='airflow_gcp',

)
```

However, when I run it I receive the following error:

```
[2017-07-20 22:38:07,478] {models.py:1441} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. 

[2017-07-20 22:38:07,490] {models.py:1462} ERROR - a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

/home/User/airflow/workspace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models.py:1927: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to MySqlOperator. Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'database': 'test'}
category=PendingDeprecationWarning

/home/User/airflow/workspace/env/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/airflow/ti_deps/deps/base_ti_dep.py:94: PendingDeprecationWarning: generator '_get_dep_statuses' raised StopIteration

for dep_status in self._get_dep_statuses(ti, session, dep_context):
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/User/airflow/workspace/env/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module> args.func(args)

File "/home/User/airflow/workspace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 422, in run pool=args.pool,

File "/home/User/airflow/workspace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 53, in wrapper result = func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/User/airflow/workspace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1374, in run result = task_copy.execute(context=context)

File "/home/User/airflow/workspace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 91, in execute files_to_upload = self._write_local_data_files(cursor)

File "/home/User/airflow/workspace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 136, in _write_local_data_files 
json.dump(row_dict, tmp_file_handle)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump 

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Does anyone know why this exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

According to your traceback, your code is breaking at [this point](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.0/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py#L136). As you can see, it process the code:

```
json.dump(row_dict, tmp_file_handle)
```

`tmp_file_handle` is a `NamedTemporaryFile` [initialized](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.0/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py#L127) with default input args, that is, it simulates a file opened with `w+b` mode (and therefore only accepts bytes-like data as input).

The problem is that in Python 2 all strings are bytes whereas in Python 3 strings are texts (encoded by default as `utf-8`).

If you open a Python 2 and run this code:

```
In [1]: from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
In [2]: tmp_f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
In [3]: import json
In [4]: json.dump({'1': 1}, tmp_f)
```

It works fine.

But if you open a Python 3 and run the same code:

```
In [54]: from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
In [55]: tmp_f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
In [56]: import json
In [57]: json.dump({'1': 1}, tmp_f)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-81743b9013c4> in <module>()
----> 1 json.dump({'1': 1}, tmp_f)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in dump(obj, fp, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    178     # a debuggability cost
    179     for chunk in iterable:
--> 180         fp.write(chunk)
    181 
    182 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py in func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    481             @_functools.wraps(func)
    482             def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
--> 483                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
    484             # Avoid closing the file as long as the wrapper is alive,
    485             # see issue #18879.

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

We get the same error as yours.

This means that Airflow is still not fully supported for Python 3 (as you can see in the [test coverage](https://codecov.io/gh/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/airflow), the module `airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py` is not yet tested either in python 2 or 3). One way to confirm this would be to run your code using python 2 and see if it works.

I'd recommend creating an issue on [their JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW) requesting portability for both versions of Python.