# Airflow integration with BgQuery Error

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, airflow

I have installed airflow and I've written a DAG to integrate MySQL data with BigQuery.

When I run the python script, I got the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name GbqConnector

I followed the instruction to downgrade pandas to an older version. When I did so I then got a different error:

> ImportError: cannot import name _test_google_api_imports

Edit: the advise from 
x97Core worked.

I have a different problem now. I am getting the following error:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py:1927: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator. Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
>
> *args: ()
>
> **kwargs: {'google_cloud_storage_connn_id': 'podioGCPConnection'}
>     category=PendingDeprecationWarning
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py:1927: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator. Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
>
> *args: ()
>
> **kwargs: {'project_id': 'podio-data'}
>     category=PendingDeprecationWarning

According to this link, the issue is with airflow's compatibility with python2 and pythn3. I've tried running the code on both but the same error still comes up. 
[Airflow mysql to gcp Dag error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226563/airflow-mysql-to-gcp-dag-error)

Does anyone know if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ran into this issue.

Downgrading the pandas version seem to work (tested on Airflow  v1.8.0):

```
pip install pandas==0.18.1
```

For more details: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1179

Or if you are using Airflow 1.8.2 or above.

```
pip install pandas-gbq
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I am getting a different error now that says  "Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'project_id': 'podio-data'}
  category=PendingDeprecationWarning". Apparently this has to do with the version of python that airflow supports, but I have tried to run my code with puthon2 and python3 and the same error comes up. Do you by chance know what the issue may be?

Comment: @Tia this new issue is unrelated to the issue which you were experiencing.  However, it seems you are passing some parameters in your default argument to dag or subdag which will be deprecated soon. If you can send me the content of your dag file, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you, the content of my dag is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076288/invalid-arguments-passed-error-for-dag-that-loads-mysql-data-to-bigquery-using

Answer (score 3):

This can be a little be complicated.
I suggest that you read these two fantastic links

```
https://wecode.wepay.com/posts/wepays-data-warehouse-bigquery-airflow
```

And Van Boxel's medium

```
https://medium.com/google-cloud/airflow-for-google-cloud-part-1-d7da9a048aa4
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using wepay as a guide.