# Airflow mysql to google cloud storage, byte-like object required error

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I am working on a DAG that queries a MySQL database, extracts and loads the data to Google Cloud Storage.

The table that I am trying to export includes text, int, float, varchar(20) and varchar(32) data.

I am using airflow v1.8.0.

```
default_args = {
    'owner' : 'tia',
    'start_date' : datetime(2018, 1, 4),
    'depends_on_past' : False,
    'retries' : 1,
    'retry_delay':timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('mysql_to_gcs', default_args=default_args)

export_waybills = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
   task_id='extract_waybills',
   mysql_conn_id = 'podiotestmySQL',
   sql = 'SELECT * FROM podiodb.logistics_waybills',
   bucket='podio-reader-storage',
   filename= 'podio-data/waybills{}.json',
   schema_filename='podio-data/schema/waybills.json',
   dag=dag)
```

I cam across the following error, which seems to be similar to this [Airflow mysql to gcp Dag error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226563/airflow-mysql-to-gcp-dag-error)

> [2018-01-04 11:12:23,372] {models.py:1342} INFO - Executing  on 2018-01-04 00:00:00
>
> [2018-01-04 11:12:23,400] {base_hook.py:67} INFO - Using connection to: 35.189.207.140
>
> [2018-01-04 11:12:24,903] {models.py:1417} ERROR - a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/hyperli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1374, in run
>
> result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
>
> File "/home/hyperli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 91, in execute
>
> files_to_upload = self._write_local_data_files(cursor)
>
> File "/home/hyperli/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 136, in _write_local_data_files
>
> json.dump(row_dict, tmp_file_handle)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/**init**.py", line 179, in dump
>       fp.write(chunk)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 622, in func_wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>
> [2018-01-04 11:12:24,907] {models.py:1433} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
>
> [2018-01-04 11:12:25,037] {models.py:1462} ERROR - a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Does anyone know why the exception is thrown?

Comment: Can you post your MySQL schema or an example of a line you are exporting?

Comment: Also please provide version of airflow.

Comment: The version of airflow is 1.8.0 and the mySQL table I'm trying to export consists of int(11), float, text, date, varchar(20) and varchar(32) data.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Check out the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using python 3? Because it seams mysql_to_gcs of the latest version (1.90) is not python compatible it seams.

It seams that this operator was changed [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/2f79610a3ef726e88dec238de000d9295ae7d2a9) to make mysql_to_gcs py3 compatible. But the [latest version(1.90)](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/d760d63e1a141a43a4a43daee9abd54cf11c894b) doesn't include [this change](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/d760d63e1a141a43a4a43daee9abd54cf11c894b/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py#L115)

Comment: Yes I am using python3. I don't get any errors when running the .py file with python3 and python2. However when I test the dag, it uses python3.

Comment: As you see in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/2f79610a3ef726e88dec238de000d9295ae7d2a9) they have only introduced support for specifically mysql_to_gcs for python 3. But this commit is not included in any currently existing version.

So it's to be expected that mysql_to_gcs will not work with python 3.

Comment: It seems like overall my system's python version is 2.7.12 and pip python is 3.5. Do you know how I can downgrade the pip python version?

Comment: You can use virtualenv to avoid such issues, see: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/